# How to create an certificate with 2 key usages using powershell 5

Tags: powershell, certificate, self-signed

I need to create a self-signed certificate to test signed emails using MimeKit.MimeKit. It requires the following KeyUsages:

- X509KeyUsageFlags.DigitalSignature
- X509KeyUsageFlags.NonRepudiation

According to documentation this [powershell](https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/self-signed-certificate-5920a7c6) command should create it:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname tosign.mycompany.pt, mycompany.pt, mycompany.pt -KeyLength 4096 
-keyUsage "DigitalSignature, NonRepudiation"
```

but it throws:

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate : Cannot bind parameter 'KeyUsage'. Cannot convert value "DigitalSignature, NonRepudiation"
```

Answer (score 1):

```
New-SelfSignedCertificate -certstorelocation cert:\localmachine\my -dnsname osign.mycompany.pt, mycompany.pt, mycompany.pt -KeyLength 4096 -keyUsage DigitalSignature,NonRepudiation
```